# bash script that kills a process while running in the background

Tags: bash, background-process, kill

I have a Canon IPF Preview Daemon that starts whenever I boot my Mac Powerbook Pro (OS 10.14.6) or I kill it using `kill`.  I have deleted the folder where the daemon resides `/Library/Printers/Canon`, emptied my `Trash` and rebooted my machine, but the daemon comes back and I can't figure out how or why.

So, I want to write a `bash` script that runs continuously in the background at boot that kills the daemon whenever it starts.

What I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                 

pid=$(ps -eo pid,comm | awk '/Canon iPF Preview Daemon.app/  {print $1; exit}')
kill $pid
```

but how do I keep this script running in the background so that it kills the daemon whenever it starts?

Since my question has been closed, I can't answer it, but I thought I'd post the answer as an edit:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                 

function killCanon() {
    pid=$(ps -eo pid,comm | awk '/Canon iPF Preview Daemon.app/  {print $1; exit}')
    if [[ $pid ]]
    then
        kill $pid
    echo Canon killed.
    fi
} # function killCanon()                                                                                                                                                                    

( while true; do killCanon;  done ) &
```

Comment: Your approach seems desperate and dangerous. But `while true; ... sleep 60; done &` will run the code in `...` forever, once per minute. (It will throw an error most of the time, because the variable `$pid` will be empty.)

Comment: This is definitely not the proper way.

Comment: @NVRM what do you mean?  What is the proper way?

Comment: @tripleee. Desperate?  Dangerous?

Comment: IDk on  a mac, but you have to find why this program is starting alone, there must be a way.